# How to remove Zathura's title bar on Mac?

Tags: macos

I'm using Neovim and my configuration for Zathura is in zathurarc. I would like to remove the title bar shown in the image[image] and I tried looking up stuff here [zathura manual](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-zathurarc/) but with no success. I believe this is not a problem on Linux but only on Mac. Can anyone help?

Comment: How is it done on Linux?

Comment: I believe it's default otherwise the manual would've added it.

Comment: Well, on macOS having a title bar is the default (for various reasons, some of them are visible on your screenshot). If Zathura just uses the default on each environment it runs on it probably lacks an option to remove the title bar (on macOS) or to show it (on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Zathura as a program has no control over it's "title bar", that is created by the window manager of whatever desktop you are using. On macOS, that would be aqua, which as far as I know will put a title bar on every window unless the program has an option to ignore aqua explicitly written into it's code (e.g. apps like alacritty or iterm).

The reason you may not have the same problem on linux is that Zathura will use whatever your window managers' decorations are, i.e. on something like i3 or bspwm it would use the *px border, and on something like openbox or Unity you would have a "title bar" similar to that of macOS.